# How to use case statement in Mode SQL with an Integer column and assign string value

Tags: sql, mode

```
    with user_industries as (
  SELECT DISTINCT company_id, industry, active_seats, revenue, seat_group, received_at FROM (
    SELECT
      nvl(u.clearbit_company_category_industry, u.company_industry) industry,
      u.received_at,
      u.company_id, 
      u.active_seats,
      CASE 
        WHEN u.active_seats >= 1 AND u.active_seats <= 2 THEN 'group_1'
        WHEN u.active_seats >= 3 AND u.active_seats <= 5 THEN 'group_2'
        WHEN u.active_seats >= 6 AND u.active_seats <= 8 THEN 'group_3'
        WHEN u.active_seats >= 9 THEN 'group_4'
      ELSE u.active_seats 
      END seat_group,
      u.revenue,
      row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY u.company_id ORDER BY u.received_at DESC) rownum
    FROM web_application_production_php.users u
  ) where rownum = 1 and received_at >= '2019-07-01'
```

When running the Case statement I want to assign a string value for use in my reports, how can I do this?

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format. And tag the DBMS you use.

Comment: There is no such thing as a `CASE` *statement* in SQL. You may mean `CASE` **expression**?

Comment: It appears as though in your CASE you already are already using strings 'group_1','group_2' etc. In the ELSE portion, you could CAST(u.active_seats AS VARCHAR(32))

Answer (score 0):

From my Coworker: Hmm, well you are assigning the seat_group to a string except when it doesn’t belong to a group, then you are assigning it to an integer. SQL doesn’t like that.
I would suggest giving the default case a value like 'group_0'rather than u.active_seats like you do now.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT company_id, industry, active_seats, revenue, seat_group, received_at FROM (
  SELECT
   nvl(u.clearbit_company_category_industry, u.company_industry) industry,
   u.received_at,
   u.company_id, 
   u.active_seats,
   CASE 
    WHEN u.active_seats >= 1 AND u.active_seats <= 2 THEN 'group_1'
    WHEN u.active_seats >= 3 AND u.active_seats <= 5 THEN 'group_2'
    WHEN u.active_seats >= 6 AND u.active_seats <= 8 THEN 'group_3'
    WHEN u.active_seats >= 9 THEN 'group_4'
   ELSE 'group_0'
   END seat_group,
   u.revenue,
   row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY u.company_id ORDER BY u.received_at DESC) rownum
  FROM web_application_production_php.users u
 ) where rownum = 1 and received_at >= '2019-07-01'
```